# Graph with graphviz

Tags: python, pandas, graphviz

I have df

```
    id, url, search_term
1, vkontakte.ru, vk
1, apple.com, iphone купить
1, asos.com, купить одежду asos
2, facebook.com, facebook
2, twitter.com, twitter
2, stackoverflow.com, how to explore decision tree python
```

And I try to build chains with arrows 
I try

```
for i, (id, domain, search_term) in enumerate(zip(df['ID'], df['domain'], df['search_term'])):
    f = Digraph('finite_state_machine', filename='fsm.gv', encoding='utf-8')
    f.body.extend(['rankdir=LR', 'size="5,5"'])
    f.attr('node', shape='circle')
    f.edge(url[i], url[i-1], label=search_term[i])
    f.view()
```

I want to add to chain all `url` and all `search_term`, but with this code I can add only two. And this code return only the first symbol of `url` and `search_term`. 
How can I do this chains?
I want to get 
[image: this graph]

Answer (score 0):

You should take the creation of the graph and the view outside the loop:

```
f = Digraph('finite_state_machine', filename='fsm.gv', encoding='utf-8')
f.body.extend(['rankdir=LR', 'size="5,5"'])
f.attr('node', shape='circle')
for i, (id, domain, search_term) in enumerate(zip(df['ID'], df['domain'], df['search_term'])):
    f.edge(url[i], url[i-1], label=search_term[i])
f.view()
```

Otherwise you create a new graph with one edge in each iteration

Comment: If I need to print the few chains. I mean that I want to print 1 chain to 1 id

Comment: @ldevyataykina so you need create the graph and iterate like that on each id seperatly

Comment: @ldevyataykina this is your code, I just modify it a little. I can't know what is the problem because I don't know what happen before and after this piece of code and you don't provide the full error or the line where the error occurred.